# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method set

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I'm getting SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set'

> "SCRIPT438: Egenskapen eller metoden set stöds inte av objektet"

in **IE8** only

Fil: dxx_libs.js, line: 48, column: 1483

We're using Backbone v0.9.2

line 48 in the backbone.lib file:

> ;this.set(a,{silent:!0});

We're using google.maps API

the error occurs when making a search for a location that should return coordinates, and a
distributor list

I don't even know where to start debugging.. 
any tips are welcome

Comment: In chrome open the developer tools (F12) and navigate to the console. Here you wil see when an error occurs and the call stack. In the call stack you should look for the last function called by your own script. Then you know which line of your code is causing the error.

Comment: the error doesn't occur in chrome only in IE8 so I'm not sure if developer tools's console helps..